# Ansible handlers get name value

Tags: ansible, handler

I have a role and I want to restart a service when file changed for an item, so I try to make a variable for the handlers, but on ansible deployment, I get file
ac

```
- name: Create jinja templating
  template:
    src: "/var/opt/config.json.j2"
    dest: "/var/opt/{{ item }}/config.json"
  with_list: "{{ variable }}"
  register: template_out
  notify:
    - my_handler
```

main/handlers.yml

```
- name: "Restart {{ item }}"
  shell: "service restart {{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ template_out.results | selectattr('changed', 'equalto', true) | list }}"


(item={u'md5sum': u'e48695da5017f1a5558b66eafc1cdccf', u'uid': 0, u'dest': u'config.yml', u'owner': u'root', 'diff': [], u'size': 4272, u'src': u'/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible_mitogen_action_1073ea002b288ef0/source', 'ansible_loop_var': u'item', u'group': u'root', 'item': u'elcos', u'checksum': u'918eb1bda64b3c9cfb14fd9f6b526cb0492fbff4', u'changed': True, 'failed': False, u'state': u'file', u'gid': 0, u'mode': u'0644', u'invocation': {u'module_args': {u'directory_mode': None, u'force': True, u'remote_src': None, u'dest': u'config.yml', u'selevel': None, u'_original_basename': u'vector_conf_elcos/elcos.toml', u'delimiter': None, u'regexp': None, u'owner': None, u'follow': False, u'validate': None, u'local_follow': None, u'src': u'/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible_mitogen_action_1073ea002b288ef0/source', u'group': None, u'unsafe_writes': None, u'checksum': u'918eb1bda64b3c9cfb14fd9f6b526cb0492fbff4', u'seuser': None, u'serole': None, u'content': None, u'setype': None, u'mode': None, u'attributes': None, u'backup': False}}})
```

so how I can fetch only the name value and not whole output

Comment: Are you really expecting a different result (i.e. closed as duplicate) by posting the [exact same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68815991/ansible-handlers) a few hours later ? If you feel like it was not justified, edit the orignal question giving details why you feel it deserves a different answer. This will give your question a chance to through the re-open vote mechanism. Thanks.

Comment: the orignal question, I edited, but always closed, it is for that a create a new one

Comment: Not to scare you out at all: you are new here and learning. But you should consider asking questions on SO and answerring as a privilege, not a right. And this privilege can actually be suspended on occasions, by automatic mechanisms or by admins, if you don't follow the rules (read the help section to learn) or post two often with bad quality. The best way not to get your question closed is to write it the best you can in first place. The re-open journey can take some time. In worst cases, note you should be able to delete you own question as long as there yet no answers on it.

Comment: I delelte the original question

Comment: It would actually have been much better the other way around: deleting this one and wait for re-opening on the other side...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    variable:
      - memcached
      - apache

  tasks:
    - name: Create jinja templating
      template:
        src: "config.json.j2"
        dest: "{{ item }}_config.json"
      with_list: "{{ variable }}"
      register: template_out
      notify: "Restart Service"

  handlers:
    - name: Restart Service
      shell: "service restart {{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ template_out.results
                      | selectattr('changed', 'equalto', true)
                      | map(attribute='item')
                      | list }}"
```

I recommend using this handler to restart services:

```yaml
    - name: Restart service
      service:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        state: restarted
      loop: "{{ service_restart.results
                | selectattr('changed', 'equalto', true)
                | map(attribute='item')
                | list }}"
```